# Spring Security 3 Hash Password Encoders

Tags: java, spring, hash, spring-security

I have an application uses Spring Security 3 application. There are some choices for hash:

```
<password-encoder hash="many options">
```

Which one is more secure one and what are the advantages/disadvantages of it over others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is not really a Spring question.
You should opt for the most secure algorithm.
For example you should avoid `md4` since MD4 is insecure.
Also you should opt to `sha-256` over `md5`. These are actual options for the password-encoder element.
`{sha}` if I recall is used along with LDAP stores.
And of course you could inject your own implementation of `password-encoder`

Comment: What are {sha} and {ssha} for?

Comment: I think you use them along with LDAP stores

Comment: MD5 is also broken (collision resistance broken).